# как определить модель телефона через js

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1] || ''
    );
}
</script>
<script>document.write(getURLParameter("brand") + (" ") + getURLParameter("model"))</script>
```

Использую такой вариант. В `url` отображается, но не выводит на страницу.

Comment: покажите пример Url для полноты картины

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос и код вопроса не соответствуют друг другу. Определение модели телефона - через который сидит пользователь, это другое. У вас скорее - как вывести параметры из адресной строки.

Так вот `document.write` - очень плохой способ модификации документа, попробуйте вывести в элемент на странице: предположим на странице существует

```
<div id="elementToModelOutput"></div>
```

тогда такой скрипт выведет в него нужные параметры

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("elementToModelOutput").innerHTML =  getURLParameter("brand") + " " + getURLParameter("model");
});
```

Но замечу - так выводить не безопасно, т.к. параметре адреса может содержаться скрипт - и злоумушленник, кинув такую ссылку "админу" может утащить его аккаунт - XSS уязвимость.

Comment: спасибо, а как определить модели телефона - через который сидит пользователь?

Comment: @Igordjan это нельзя сделать напрямую http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356347/detecting-device-brand . Но косвенно - можно через плагин http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/